# How can I add a background image to my footer when floating other elements within the footer element?

Tags: html, css, xhtml

Can anyone plese explain to me why my image in the footer css doesn't appear as the background? I have both a small unordered list that serves as a navigational menu and the footers main content floated to the left and right respectively, I feel like they are obstructing, however I figured their default value would be transparent.... Any hints please? I am new to this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML       4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
http-equiv="content-type">
<title>title</title>
<style type="text/css" media="screen, print, projection">
body{
    background: #DAA520;
}
#wrap {
    width:1000px;
    margin:0 auto;
    background: white;
}
#alldivs{
}
#header{ 
    background: blue;
    height: 150px;
}
#nav{
    background: yellow;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    background:white repeat-x;
    width:100%;
    float:left;
    border: 1px solid #42432d;
    border-width:1px 0;
}
#nav li{
    display: inline;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
#nav a:link,
#nav a:visited {
    color:#000;
    background:#FFFFF0;
    float:center;
    width:auto;
    border-right:1px solid #42432d;
    text-decoration:none;
    font:bold 1em/1em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    text-transform:uppercase;
}
#nav a:hover,
#nav a:focus {
    color:#fff;
    background:blue;
}
#main{
    background: white;
    float: left;
    width: 780px;
    padding: 10px;
}
#sidebar{
    background: gray;
    float: right;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 180px;
}
#footer{
    width: 1000px;
    height: 150px;
    clear: both;
    background-image:url(linktopicture.jpg);
}
#footernav li{
    display: inline;
}
#footernav a:link,
#footernav a:visited {
    color:gray;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    padding-left: 15px;
}
#footer ul{
    float: left;
    width: 500px;
    margin: 0px;
    padding-top: 35px;
    padding-bottom: 3px
    text-align: left;
}
#footercontent {
    width: 490px:
    float: right;
    text-align: right;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
}


</style> 
</head>



<body>
<br>
<div id="alldivs">
<div id ="wrap">
<div id="header"><img src="linktopicture" alt="text"/> </div>
<ul id="nav">
<li id="home"><a href="homelink">HOME</a></li>
<li id="services"><a href="serviceslink">SERVICES</a></li>
<li id="contact"><a href="linkcontact">CONTACT</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="main"><p>
main content

</p></div>
<div id="sidebar">sidebar space</div>
<div id="footer">
<ul id="footernav">
<li id="footernavhome"><a href="linkhome">HOME</a></li>
<li id="footernavservices"><a href="linkservices">SERVICES</a></li>
<li id="footernavcontact"><a href="linkcontact">CONTACT</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="footercontent">
<p>
blahh
</br>
blahhh

</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to [contain and clear your floats](http://css-tricks.com/795-all-about-floats/) in the footer, which will allow the  background to appear.

Here's an overly-simplified example from your original markup:

```
<div id="footer">
    <ul id="footernav">
        ...
    </ul>

    <div id="footercontent">
        ...
    </div>

    <!-- Here's the Magic -->
    <br style="clear: both; display: block;" />
</div>
```

There are many ways to clear floated elements, but arguably the most common and easiest to implement is the [clearfix approach](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/) — or the updated and *highly-recommended* [micro clearfix](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/) method.

An example of using a "clearfix" would become:

```
<div id="footer" class="clearfix">
    <ul id="footernav">
        ...
    </ul>

    <div id="footercontent">
        ...
    </div>      
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you do not want a full break, add:

```
<span class="cleaAll"></span>
```

To your html where RJB said, add:

```
.clearAll {
display:block;
height:1px;
}
```

To your css, 
Hope it helps.